# reactjs - variable showing as undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Im new to reactjs and trying to populate  a form from a value retrieved from firebase.

Here is where the value is fetched.

```
componentWillMount: function () {

    var projectId = this.props.params.key;
    this.fb = new Firebase(rootUrl + 'items/');
    var projectRef = this.fb.child(projectId);

    var subjectproject = "NA";


    projectRef.child("subject").on("value", function(snapshot) {
        subjectproject = snapshot.val();
    });


},
```

And here is the form input that i want to populate

```
<div className="col-lg-6">
           <div class="input-group">
               <label class="control-label required" for="project_project_title">Subject</label>
                     <input defaultValue={subjectproject} value={this.state.subject} placeholder="Subject" onChange={this.handleInputChangeSubject} type="text" className="form-control"/>
            </div>
  </div>
```

All i ever get is projectSubject is undefined. How do i create a variable that can be used to provide a defaultvalue.

Edit -

```
 projectRef.child("subject").on("value", function(snapshot) {
        textsubject = (snapshot.val());
        this.setState({subject: textsubject});
    });
```

Throws `FIREBASE WARNING: Exception was thrown by user callback. TypeError: this.setState is not a function`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the scope of variables in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/what-is-the-scope-of-variables-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`subjectproject` - is declared as local variable in componentWillMount. It is not visible in your render method.

See this: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html#default-value

```
The defaultValue and defaultChecked props are only used during initial render.
```

Example(from comment):

```
componentWillMount: function () {
    var self = this;

   // some code

    projectRef.child("subject").on("value", function(snapshot) {
        self.setState({
            subjectproject: snapshot.val()
        });
    });


},
```

Comment: How would i go about making it usable in the form?

Comment: Ok so default value is wrong? How would i go about updating the box after the data is fetched?

Comment: When data is fetched you should use `this.setState` method to set data to `state[propertyName]`. And then you can use `this.state[propertyName]` anywhare in your `render` method

Comment: Ive edited my post. If i try setState from inside the function it throws an error. Whats the correct way of doing it? If i use setState outside with other data it sets it fine.

Comment: I have edited my answer too :) `this` must point to correct object.

Comment: Beautiful. Thank you very much. Much appreciated.